# MX Record Question

Tags: email, dns

Is there a way to bypass the DNS's MX record?  My company uses Barracuda for spam filtering and our company's MX record points to Barracuda.  A product we're trying to build needs to talk TLS to the mail server, but to test this I have to create a subdomain that bypasses Barracuda and then having to deal with the SSL certs for that.  Not necessarily a show stopper.  But if I could fool something to use our mail server's actual IP address as opposed to the MX, that'd help a lot.

Any thought, cantor, ideas or anecdotes?

Comment: You can certain configure your MTA to override the DNS MX record for a specific domain and send instead to a hardcoded name or IP adress, but the way you configure that entirely depends on what MTA you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You could always set the Barracuda hostname to the IP address of your mail server in /etc/hosts on the new product server instance. It's an ugly hack, but it should work if your host uses standard DNS resolver libraries.

Oh, and it will break TLS, too, since there would be a name mismatch with the SSL certificate.